# Slick after commit hook

Tags: database, scala, slick, playframework-2.3

is it possible to register tasks after a successful slick transaction? I don't want to duplicate this code to every possible endpoint of the transaction. (Like Hibernate afterTransactionCompletion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not part of the API. You may be able to get the desired behavior by overriding something in your Slick Driver. Consider opening a ticket at slick/slick